# above n references broken

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

EDIT:  Added the complete cite macro from my aglc2.cbx file.
EDIT:  Added the cite:save macro as suggested by domwass
EDIT:  Added these links to files to reproduce the problem
UPDATE: I think I have this solved now.  Key was as @domwass suggested to create a `cite:save` macro.  Updated code is below

- [tmp.tex](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45413003/tex_issue/tmp.tex) - contains sample code
- [tmp.pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45413003/tex_issue/tmp.pdf) - this is what it looks like
- [bibliography.bib](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45413003/tex_issue/bibliography.bib) - needs no introduction
- [lawessay.cls](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45413003/tex_issue/lawessay.cls) - lawessay style I use for the tex source (adapted from Will Hardy's style)
- [aglc2.bbx](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45413003/tex_issue/aglc2.bbx) - BBX file for the lawessay style
- [aglc2.cbx](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45413003/tex_issue/aglc2.cbx) - CBX file.  The code snippet below comes from this

---

Hi, I think this is a newbie question.  In my biblatex `cite` macro I have this code:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:save}{%
    \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
    \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}%
}

\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
\global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
\ifciteseen
{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {%
            % citeibid is true and this citation has been seen on this page previously
            % and citation is in a footnote
            \usebibmacro{cite:ibid}%
        } {%else
            % either citeibid is false or this is the first time the citation appears
            % on this page
            \ifthenelse{\(\equal{\thefield{entrytype}}{jurisdiction}\or%
                    \equal{\thefield{entrytype}}{legislation}\or%
                    \equal{\thefield{entrytype}}{legal}\)%
                \or\not\ifciteseen}
                    {%
                % If the entry is a jurisdiction or legislation or legal
                % or if the citation has not been seen before
                % ie: this is how to print a first citation.  Legislation, legal and
                % jurisdictions are always printed as though they were a first citation.
                \usebibmacro{cite:short}%
            } {% else
                % Must be something else or a subsequent citation
                \usebibmacro{author/editor:surname}%
                                   above n\addnbspace%
                                    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
            }
        } {%
            % shorthand field is defined
            \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        }
    }
} {%
    % citation has not been seen before
    \usebibmacro{cite:full}
}
}
```

So when a footnote is printed as ...'above n xx' the xx is the page number.  How can I set it to be the footnote number?

Comment: You are explicitly asking for the page number because of the `pageref`.

Comment: Yes but I want the footnote number instead.  How do I do that?

Comment: No idea. You should add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows how you are using `\cite` with `\footnote`. At the moment it is very hard to see what's going on.

Comment: @Martin I have edited the original post

Comment: Oh sigh I have been on this all morning and it's driving me nutty.  If I replace `\printlist[last]{pageref}` with `\the\value{instcount}` I get the footnote number of the previous time the item is cited but not the first time it is cited.

Answer (score 3):

Before you refer back to the first citation of an entry, you have to save the information. In order to do that, you could create a bibmacro:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:save}{%
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}
```

You then have to call this bibmacro in the cite-bibmacro, in the second mandatory argument of the `\ifciteseen` test (and thus, only when the entry is cited for the first time):

```
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  […]
  \ifciteseen
    {[…]}
    {[…]
     \usebibmacro{cite:save}}}
```

Now, every time you want to refer back to the first entry, you use the following lines:

```
\bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}%
***\label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}***}
```

Thus, the bibmacro that you posted could be modified as follows (I have not tested it!):

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:save}{%
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
\global\boolfalse{cbx@loccit}%
\ifciteseen
{%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {%
            % citeibid is true and this citation has been seen on this page previously
            % and citation is in a footnote
            \usebibmacro{cite:ibid}%
        } {%else
            % either citeibid is false or this is the first time the citation appears
            % on this page
            \ifthenelse{\(\equal{\thefield{entrytype}}{jurisdiction}\or%
                    \equal{\thefield{entrytype}}{legislation}\or%
                    \equal{\thefield{entrytype}}{legal}\)%
                \or\not\ifciteseen}
                    {%
                % If the entry is a jurisdiction or legislation or legal
                % or if the citation has not been seen before
                % ie: this is how to print a first citation.  Legislation, legal and
                % jurisdictions are always printed as though they were a first citation.
                \usebibmacro{cite:short}%
            } {% else
                % Must be something else or a subsequent citation
                \usebibmacro{author/editor:surname}%
                \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace%
                \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
            }
        } {%
            % shorthand field is defined
            \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
        }
    }
} {%
    % citation has not been seen before
    \usebibmacro{cite:full}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:save}%
}
}
```

But note that this does only work if every citation is inside a footnote. If you also cite in the text, and the first citation of an entry is in the text and not in a footnote, the reference won’t work. This is why biblatex’s style `verbose-note` differentiates between citations in footnotes and citations in the text. Thus, the code there is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: many thanks.  I will try this and let you know how it goes.  I had another question.  How do you know this?  I have been through biblatex.pdf and have been searching but I can't find any instruction on anything like what you just did.  Is this kind of stuff documented anywhere?

Comment: @Mark: Well, I use biblatex quite from the outset of its development, and I have written some biblatex styles, so I know of some internals that a normal user does not have to bother with. In this particular case, I knew that a similar functionality is provided by `verbose-note`, and thus I had a look into `verbose-note.cbx` and adapted the code a bit.

Comment: It has been a long time but I finally got round to implementing this (another assignment due!).  From what I can gather the cite:save macro runs correctly and only runs the first time.  But the subsequent references show a '??' instead of the number.  I suspect this means it either isn't saving the reference or can't retrieve it.  Would you mind sending some pointers on how I can debug this?  I have worked out that `entrykey' and `instcount' are correct at the time `cite:save' is run but I can't work out how to troubleshoot the retrieval part.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example with the code that you have so far?

Comment: links to source added to the original post.

Comment: I have this sorted I think.  The `cite:save` macro was missing a label command (I found this in your `footref` macro in footref-dw).  Adding that `\label` seems to have fixed things.  I have modified the snippet above to reflect this.

Comment: For anyone else who is interested in this, Mark's edit (to include the label) is in the wrong place.  The `\label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}%` code must be in `cite:save`, not in the normal `cite` macro.