# biblatex-chicago + a 'seenote' cross-reference

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm trying to modify biblatex-chicago to meet the idiosyncratic style of a specific journal.  One thing they insist on is that subsequent citations of a work should appear in a shortened form along with a reference to the note where the full citation may be found; e.g.:

Goossens, Mittelbach, and Samarin, *LaTeX Companion* (see n. 1), 23--32.

Following the advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15611/above-n-references-broken), I looked into `biblatex`'s `verbose-note.cbx` and made the following additions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:save}{% <--- based on verbose-note.cbx
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inreference}\OR%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{reference}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
    {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
      \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
         \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\printnames{labelname}%
        \isdot\classicpunct}}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
\addspace% <--- additions start here
\mkbibparens{%
  \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace%
  \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}}}%
  }%

\begin{document}

Test.%
\footnote{\cite{companion}.}%
Test.%
\footnote{\mancite\cite{companion}.}%

\end{document}
```

This does not work (nor have my more elaborate attempts), and I keep wasting time worrying about this when I still have revisions to do.  I would appreciate any pointers as to why this solution is incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\ref` has no target, since there is no `\label` defined. Thus, you have to add a `\label` to your `cite:save` bibmacro. I have improved your example accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:save}{% <--- based on verbose-note.cbx
  \savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@lastkey}% <-- this is in the original chicago-notes.cbx
  \csxdef{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
  \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inreference}\OR%
    \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{reference}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{magazine}% Simplify .bib creation
    {\ifuseauthor%
      {\printfield[journaltitle]{journaltitle}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{manual}%
      {\printlist{organization}\isdot\newcunit}%
      {}}}%
  {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon}%
    {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}%
      \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{authortype}{anon?}%
      {\bibleftbracket\printnames{labelname}?%
         \bibrightbracket\classicpunct}%
      {\printnames{labelname}%
        \isdot\classicpunct}}}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
\addspace% <--- additions start here
\mkbibparens{%
  \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace%
  \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@\thefield{entrykey}}}}%
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test.%
\footnote{\cite{companion}.}
Test.%
\footnote{\mancite\cite{companion}.}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, OK.  I had tried both of your additions to the `cite:save` macro, but since my attempts at adding a label were clearly incorrect, I stripped them from my more basic example.  The solution seems so simple and obvious now that I see it before me; thanks!